# c# mouse leave event

Tags: c#, forms, mouseevent

In .NET 4.5.1 I am making a Windows Form with some checkboxes in it:

[image]

I would like for the form to close when the MouseLeaves it, so I added the MouseLeaveEvent to the form in the designer:

```
    private void JobViewerLegendForm_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

But I get an event every time the mouse levaes one of the checkboxes or the label and the sender seems to be the top checkbox named Canvas and not the form it self. If I set .Enable=false for all checkboxes it starts working as intended, that is the sender becomes only the form it self. It seems that the first component takes ontrol of the mouse event somehow, but I don't understand how this works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when your mouse Enters the `CheckBox` es boundary it already leaved the `Form` and the event fires.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I tried the condition  if (sender == this) Close(); But I think this turned out to be a tautology. But thanks for the input.

Comment: When the event is raised, just check the current mouse position and see whether it's outside the bounds of the form. If it's not then you know it's over a child control.

Comment: @DrDress This is how it works. Reading again slowly with glasses on,  
Gholamalih has pointed out the right thing.

Comment: One addition: it seems you are using .NET Framework and not .NET. I tested the behavior in .NET6.0 and the event only fires once if you are outside the window. Maybe it is feasible for you to upgrade directly to .NET6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Timer` component and leave it's `Enabled` to `False` and in the timer tick event, use this code:

```
Point dl = DesktopLocation;
Point ml = MousePosition;

if (!((ml.X >= dl.X && ml.X <= dl.X + Width) && (ml.Y >= dl.Y && ml.Y <= dl.Y + Height)))
{
    Close();
}
```

and make the `Timer` enable, in `MouseEnter` event of the `Form`.

Comment: Since it's a borderless Form, without a Timer, just write in the MouseLeave event: `if (!RectangleToScreen(ClientRectangle).Contains(MousePosition)) Close();`. Perhaps making the event `async` to await a second before that as close conformation would be a good idea as well.